# Loop on different types of nodes sequentially in SQL XML datatype

Tags: sql-server, xml

In my SQL Server table one column has datatype as XML. It contains data as:

```
<P1>
    <P2>
        <P3 name='[1] name1', value='val1'> </P3>
        <P4 name='[1] name2', value='val2'> </P4>
        <P3 name='[2] name3', value='val3'> </P3>
        <P5 name='[1] name4', value='val4'> </P5>
        <P3 name='[3] name5', value='val5'> </P3>
    </P2>
</p1>
```

How can I loop on this data to get all the names and values sequentially?

I have tried this using a stored procedure as:

```
BEGIN

        DECLARE @sql1 NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10),
        @sql2 NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @sql3 NVARCHAR(MAX);
    set nocount on;
    set @sql1 = N'SELECT tbl.Id' + @CRLF +
    N', c.value(''@name'',''VARCHAR(max)'') AS [name]' + @CRLF +
    N', c.value(''@value'',''VARCHAR(max)'') AS [value]' + @CRLF +
    N'FROM table AS tbl' + @CRLF +
    N'CROSS APPLY tbl.DataXML.nodes(''/P1/P2/P3'') AS t(c)' + @CRLF +
    N'where id=@ID';
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql1, N'@ID [nvarchar](50)', @ID;
    set @sql2 = N'SELECT tbl.Id' + @CRLF +
    N', c.value(''@name'',''VARCHAR(max)'') AS [name]' + @CRLF +
    N', c.value(''@value'',''VARCHAR(max)'') AS [value]' + @CRLF +
    N'FROM table AS tbl' + @CRLF +
    N'CROSS APPLY tbl.DataXML.nodes(''/P1/P2/P4'') AS t(c)' + @CRLF +
    N'where id=@ID';
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql2, N'@ID [nvarchar](50)', @ID;
    set @sql3 = N'SELECT tbl.Id' + @CRLF +
    N', c.value(''@name'',''VARCHAR(max)'') AS [name]' + @CRLF +
    N', c.value(''@value'',''VARCHAR(max)'') AS [value]' + @CRLF +
    N'FROM table AS tbl' + @CRLF +
    N'CROSS APPLY tbl.DataXML.nodes(''/P1/P2/P5'') AS t(c)' + @CRLF +
    N'where id=@ID';

END
```

In the output I am getting names and values in the order: all P3 type names, then all P4, then all P5. But I want to loop such that I will get the output as it is stored in XML data.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: @DaleK I have added my attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @x xml = N'
<P1>
    <P2>
        <P3 name="[1] name1" value="val1"> </P3>
        <P4 name="[1] name2" value="val2"> </P4>
        <P3 name="[2] name3" value="val3"> </P3>
        <P5 name="[1] name4" value="val4"> </P5>
        <P3 name="[3] name5" value="val5"> </P3>
    </P2>
</P1>
';

select 
    t.col.value('(@name)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as name,
    t.col.value('(@value)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as value
from @x.nodes('/P1/P2/*[@name and @value]') as t(col);

--or (for P3, P4, P5)
select 
    t.col.value('(@name)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as name,
    t.col.value('(@value)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as value
from @x.nodes('/P1/P2/*[local-name() = ("P3", "P4", "P5")]') as t(col);
```